# Counterfactual Contrasts in a Hierarchical model using emmeans()

Tags: inference, lsmeans, counterfactuals

--REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE INCLUDED! See below --

Hi!  I'm attempting to measure a difference in sales using a *Controlled Interrupted Time-Series* methodology; that is, I have a collection of 'exposed' and 'unexposed' time series and I am trying to infer the effect of an exposure based on the magnitude of *level-change* and *slope-change* in the estimated trend of the time series.

To add a wrinkle, I'm using a linear mixed model to give each subject its own trend over time; because of this (and the fact that my effect of interest is encoded as multiple coefficients/interactions in the model) I'm trying using the *emmeans* package to compute the marginal mean for the sales difference between the estimated trend of the 'exposed' subjects and the estimated *counterfactual trend* of the 'exposed' subjects *if they had been unexposed*.

Here's some simulated data:

```
library(tippy)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
library(fdrtool)

# A function to generate the sales based on an underlying model (don't peek!)
simulate_sales_data <- function(geo_df){ 
  lapply(geo_df$geo_name, function(g){
  
  which = geo_df$exposure[geo_df$geo_name == g]
  # Determine the geo's unique intercept/slope/season terms
  
  int <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 1000)
  slope = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 5)
  
  sine = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 500, sd = 1)
  cosine = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 500, sd = 1)
  
  # Now generate a deflection 
  
  era_levelchange = if(which){rnorm(n = 1, mean = 60, sd = 10)}else{rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 5)}
  era_slopechange = if(which){rnorm(n = 1, mean = 20, sd = 1)}else{rnorm(n = 1, mean = 1, sd = 1)}
  
  # Now generate residuals
  epsilon <- rnorm(n = 105, mean = 0, sd = 500)
  
  time_seq <- 0:104*7
  
  s2 <- 10000 + int + time_seq*slope + sine*sin(time_seq * 2*pi/365) + cosine*cos(time_seq * 2*pi/365) +
    era_levelchange * (time_seq > 365) + era_slopechange * (time_seq - 365) * (time_seq > 365) + epsilon
    
  return(data.frame(geo_name = g, time = time_seq, sales = s2))}) %>% 
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, .) %>% 
    left_join(geo_df, by = "geo_name") %>% 
    mutate(
      exposure_label = factor(exposure, levels = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c("Unexposed", "Exposed")),
      era = factor(case_when(time >= 365 ~'Post', TRUE ~ 'Pre'), levels = c("Pre", "Post")))
}


# Initialize some parameters
geographies <- data.frame(geo_name = paste0("G", 1:40))
exposure_start_time = 365
set.seed(8675309)


# Randomly assign the exposure (unexposed=0, exposed=1) status
geographies$exposure <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 40, replace = TRUE)

# Now create the sales figures - the generating mechanism is a secret :)  
salesdata <- simulate_sales_data(geographies) %>% filter(time <= 545)
  

# Let's assign pretend dates to the time variable so it makes sense on a calendar
salesdata$saledate <- as.Date(salesdata$time, origin = "2021-01-01")


# A little cleanup
salesdata$exposure <- factor(salesdata$exposure, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE))
salesdata$era <- factor(salesdata$era, levels = c("Post", "Pre"))

# examine the sales as a plot
ggplot(data = salesdata, aes(x = time, y = sales, group = geo_name, color = geo_name, linetype = exposure)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 365, linetype = 2) +
  annotate("label", x = 365, y = 10500, label = "Start of Media") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey93"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey93"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

# Or like this (different plot)
  filter(salesdata, geo_name %in% c(
  salesdata %>% distinct(geo_name, exposure) %>% group_by(exposure) %>% filter(row_number() < 7) %>% {.$geo_name})) %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = time, y = sales, group = geo_name, color = geo_name, linetype = exposure)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 365, linetype = 2) +
  annotate("label", x = 365, y = 15000, label = "Start of Media") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey93"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey93"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  facet_wrap(~geo_name)
```

[image: trend1]

[image: trend2]

Here's my model that I'm fitting:

```
mdl <- lmer(sales ~ (1 + time + era*exposure_spline + (sin(time * 2*pi/365)) + (cos(time * 2*pi/365)) | geo_name) + (era+exposure_spline):exposure, data = salesdata)
```

Here, I'm attempting to give each geography a random intercept, slope, and seasonal (sinusoidal) trend, AS WELL as a random level+ slope change based on which 'era' it is (either 'Pre'- or 'Post'-intervention).  'Era' and 'exposure' are also included as fixed effects because my ultimate goal will be to compare the *average level+slope change among exposed subjects* to the *average level+slope change samong unexposed subjects*.

Now, where I run into trouble is how to estimate a grid of counterfactual predictions (for only the EXPOSED subjects).  I started with something along the lines of

```
emmeans(mdl2, ~era*exposure, counterfactuals = "exposure")
```

But this isn't correct and my lack of familiarity with *emmeans* is making this really difficult to figure out.  I think my problem is that I want to use the *exposure* as a counterfactual variable (i.e., estimate means for every subject as if it were both an 'exposed' AND an 'unexposed') but also as a subsetting variable (i.e., I am only interested in the counterfactual comparisons among the subjects that were unexposed.)

The counterfactual is fairly easy to estimate in terms of its mean value (can just create a copy of the dataset where exposure = 'Unexposed' for all subjects) but obviously this doesn't preserve the standard error of the estimates so I can't do inferential testing on these differences. Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to estimate:

```
salesdata$pred2 <- predict(mdl, newdata = salesdata)

# Now construct a counterfactual prediction and add it to the dataset
salesdata$pred_counterfactual2 <- predict(mdl, newdata = mutate(salesdata, exposure = "FALSE", exposure_label = "Unexposed"))

# Take a look at some predictions
salesdata_subset <- 
  filter(salesdata, geo_name %in% c(
  salesdata %>% 
    distinct(exposure, geo_name) %>% 
    group_by(exposure) %>% 
    head(16) %>%
    {.$geo_name}))

g <- 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = salesdata_subset, aes(x = saledate, y = sales), alpha = 0.22) +
  geom_line(data = salesdata_subset, aes(x = saledate, y = pred2, color = exposure)) +
  geom_line(data = filter(salesdata_subset, era == 'Post', exposure == TRUE), aes(x = saledate, y = pred_counterfactual2, color = exposure, linetype = "Counterfactual")) +
  scale_x_date("Date", date_breaks = "4 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Counterfactual" = 2)) +
  facet_wrap(~geo_name) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey93"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey93"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image: counterfactuals]

**Ultimately, I'm looking for a way to test whether the difference between the solid red lines and the dashed red lines is statistically significant.**  Any stats folks out there that can point me in the right direction?  Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that as long as you have no link function or response transformation, the `counterfactuals` argument makes no difference anyway. So the expedient thing to do is skip it and just use `emmeans()` conventionally.